# JQuery on media query elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
 <div class = "header>
</div>

.header{
position:relative
color:green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
.header{
position:fixed
color:blue;
}
}
```

I have a div that has a positioning of relative, and in a media query I change that to fixed. I am now trying to target the media query div, however it's modifying the original div. Any suggestions? My attempt was to make the JS check the screen width but this did not work.

*Just to clarify I would like my Javascript to apply for the media query div header.*

```
if(screen.width<400){
        console.log('yes');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".header").css("top", Math.max(0,30 - $(this).scrollTop()));
    });}
```

Comment: `I am now trying to target the media query div, however it's modifying the original div.`:- what target and original you are talking about? I can't see?

Comment: .header is a div with position:relative in my main CSS. I have a media query targeting mobile phones, this div is set to position:fixed. I would like this script to be reference to .header of the media query, and not the main CSS.

Comment: added some basic html/css to demonstrate. I thought it was quite clear, sorry.

Comment: This isn't clear at all? The media query doesn't create a new element, you still only have one single element, that you seem to successfully target ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me clarify... you don't have 2 divs. You have 1 div and the browser applies the style indicated... ie: when the screen is large, it applies the regular style :

```
.header{
    position:relative
    color:green;
}
```

When you are in mobile it applies:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
    .header{
        position:fixed
        color:blue;
    }
}
```

They are both acting on the exact same thing.. just different rules on styling. So you can't "target" one or the other because they are the same exact element. If you could put this into a jsfiddle or a codepen to replicate, it would be easier to see what you have.

If you are just trying to overwrite the media query style, what you are doing should work, or using getComputedStyle(element).[property]